# [^/]+ explanation in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this htaccess code

```
RewriteRule   ^/([uge])/([^/]+)$  /$1/$2/
```

But I couldn't really understand what does `[^/]+` do?
I've been searching this on Google for awhile, but I couldn't get what I wanted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two basic regex constructs here

**Character class**

[See character classes on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

`[...]` is a character class, means this construct matches one character from the class (from inside the square brackets).

Your class starts with a `^`, that gives the character class a special meaning, its a **negated character class** (`[^...]`), means matches anything thats not part of the class.

**Quantifier**

[See quantifiers on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

`+` is a quantifier, meaning 1 or more

**Meaning of your regex**

To understand what this is doing you have also to take the next thing into account, the `$` at the end. This is an anchor that matches the end of the string.

[See anchors on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

so `([^/]+)$` matches all characters at the end of the string that are not slashes.

Here you can also find a [basic tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: thanks. I think this is the best explanation for a beginner, like me.

Answer (score 8):

`[^/]` means any character not matching `/`.

Answer (score 3):

That means:

> Match 1 or more characters until forward slash `/` is found

Anything in square brackets `[` and `]` that has caret `^` at the start acts has negation and hence:

> `[^/]` means any character except `/`
>
> `[^/]+` means 1 or more characters except `/`

Answer (score 3):

`[any_character]` is a Character Classes or Character Sets [<sup>charclass Ref</sup>](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `[^any_character]` is a negated Character Classes or Character Sets [<sup>charclass negated Ref</sup>](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

From [Anchors Ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

> Remember `^` also has the meaning: *The caret ^ matches the position before the first character in the string (an Anchor)* when not used inside a Character class.

From [charclass Ref: Metacharacters Inside Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> Note that the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (), the caret (^) and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. To search for a star or plus, use [+*]. Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.

From [Repitition <sup>Ref</sup>](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
`+` means one or more chracters.

so, `[^/]+`

Means match any character other than `/`. So, it will match until a `/` is encountered.

---

For `^/([uge])/([^/]+)$`

> - the string should begin with **/**
> - followed by character **u** or **g** or **e**
> - followed by **/**
> - followed and ended by one or more any character other than **/**

the `()` (round brackets)  are used for : Round Brackets Create a Backreference [<sup>Ref</sup>](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 2):

The expression `[^/]` matches any character that is not the `/`, and the quantor `+` denotes that the expression to the left of the quantor has to appear at leat one time.